# How to add custom preamble to the signal?

Tags: unetstack

We are having our `custom preamble` that we wish to add to the signal, Is there a way to save the `custom preamble` to the modem and load it to `phy[3]` as shown in [UnetDocumentation(sec 16.4)](https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_baseband_service.html#16.4._Transmitting_and_detecting_preambles).

Is there any other method to load the preamble directly to the signal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply need to transmit a preamble with the signal, you have two options:

1. You could just include it as part of your signal directly.
2. You could set the preamble on a specific indexed scheme (e.g. `phy[3]`) and then use that for your transmission.

The advantage of method 1 is its simplicity. The advantage of method 2 is that you can also use the preamble for detection of signals in the water.

Method 1 is trivial, and so I won't discuss it here in detail. I'll focus on showing you how method 2 works:

**Step 1. Set up your preamble.**

If you are using a *standard* signal such as a m-sequence or a chirp, you can set it up by specifying the parameters of the signal. Examples:

```
phy[3].preamble = Preamble.hfmUpSweep(240)  // 240-sample long hyperbolic up sweep
phy[3].preamble = Preamble.mseq(1023,2)     // 1023-chip m-sequence with 50% bandwidth
```

(type `help phy[].preamble` on the unet shell, and refer to [`Preamble`](https://unetstack.net/javadoc/3.3/org/arl/yoda/Preamble.html) API docs for more information)

If you have a custom signal as a preamble, you can specify the baseband signal directly:

```
phy[3].preamble = new Preamble(pre)
```

where `pre` contains the complex baseband samples.

**Step 2. Transmit using your preamble.**

When transmitting a baseband signal, you can specify a preamble to use. For example:

```
phy << new TxBasebandSignalReq(preamble: 3, signal: signal)
```

where `3` specifies that `phy[3]` preamble should be transmitted, and `signal` contains your baseband signal samples to transmit after the preamble.

**TIP**: If you want to use the preamble for signal detection, you need to set the detection threshold for the scheme (e.g. `phy[3].threshold = 0.25`). Since this isn't the focus of this question, we won't dwell on it much.

**NOTE**: While the `Preamble` class supports arbitrary length preamble signals, practical modems may have hard limits based on memory buffers, and soft limits based on computational load for detection. For most practical UnetStack-based modems today, you probably want to limit the preamble signals to 1024 samples or less (or check with your modem vendor on hardware limits).

Comment: Thank you Dr.Mandar for your answer. I had tried to load the preamble the way you suggested, I am having strange issue where after loading the preamble using `phy[3].preamble = new Preamble(pre)`  and setting the detection threshold `phy[3].threshold = 0.25` when i `subscribe phy`, it is receiving something continuously and i had hydrophone in the water where i can confirm there is no physical transmission. In the log it gives us `severe` flag and i need to manually restart the modem. Could you please comment on that ?

Comment: If your preamble is short, the matched filter output may be quite noisy. Try a larger threshold. The threshold value can be between 0 and 1, and we typically use 0.25 to 0.30 for preambles with good correlation properties and about 20-40 ms in duration.